# Why won't my data points appear in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am trying to use RStudio to make a scatterplot, and I'm having trouble getting the data points to appear in the plot. The x/y axes and title appear as they should, just not the data points. The code I am running appears below. Is there something I'm missing?

```
library("rjson")
input <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\...\\Steam_Usage_Data.json") 
print(input)
attach(input)
plot(Tempature, Usage,
     ylab = "Tempature (degrees F)",
     xlab = "Steam Usage (in lbs)",
     xlim = c(180, 680),
     ylim = c(21, 80),
     main = "Tempature vs Usage",
     pch = 21,
     bg = "purple",
     col = "purple",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming there is something wrong with your code, but you haven't shown us your data. Remember, a plot requires both data *and* code to display correctly.

Let's test the assumption that there is something wrong with your code, by generating a data frame with columns called `Tempature` and `Usage` that are numeric and in the same range as the limits you have set for your plot:

```r
input <- data.frame(Tempature = runif(15, 180, 680), Usage = runif(15, 21, 80))
print(input)
#>    Tempature    Usage
#> 1   186.3152 50.06855
#> 2   650.1329 45.11103
#> 3   310.3517 58.12774
#> 4   673.9505 62.78454
#> 5   541.5043 23.15009
#> 6   459.8498 58.61954
#> 7   669.0384 21.09162
#> 8   619.1251 50.80039
#> 9   614.7532 39.73166
#> 10  667.0356 27.01400
#> 11  208.8908 42.36691
#> 12  649.0522 24.13038
#> 13  460.6605 61.61682
#> 14  508.6526 58.55389
#> 15  483.0430 40.79204
```

Now we will use the *exact* code that you used in your example:

```r
attach(input)
plot(Tempature, Usage,
     ylab = "Tempature (degrees F)",
     xlab = "Steam Usage (in lbs)",
     xlim = c(180, 680),
     ylim = c(21, 80),
     main = "Tempature vs Usage",
     pch = 21,
     bg = "purple",
     col = "purple",
)
```

[image]

We can see that given the correct data, your plotting code works as expected. What this means is that you are making some unfounded assumption about your data. Since you didn't include the data in your question, we can only speculate about what this might be. A few possibilities are:

1. You may have mis-typed the column names: Note that "Tempature" is spelled wrongly - it should be "Temperature"
2. Your data may not have been imported properly. Check that both `Usage` and `Tempature` are numeric, rather than factor columns. You can do `input$Tempature <- as.numeric(as.character(input$Tempature))` and `input$Usage <- as.numeric(as.character(input$Usage))` to make sure these are actually numeric.
3. You may have variables called `Tempature` or `Usage` in the global workspace which are masking the columns in your data frame. This is one of the reasons why you should never use `attach`. You should change the first line of `plot` to `plot(input$Tempature, input$Usage,`
4. You may be setting the axis ranges outside of where the actual data is. I think this is the most likely explanation given that the axes are drawn properly. Try removing the `xlim` and `ylim` from your plot so that automatic limits are set. Usually R will choose a nice range for the displayed data anyway.